# UpperCase Input não funciona em document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

Tenho um input:

```
<input id="id_nome" name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase" autofocus required>
```

Quando digito ele fica maiúsculo graças ao `transform: uppercase`, porém quando tento ler o conteúdo do campo através de:

```
alert(document.getElementById('id_nome').value)
```

o valor aparece minusculo. Como faço para ele aparecer maiúsculo também?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente assim:

```js
valor = document.getElementById('id_nome').value.toUpperCase();
alert(valor);
```

```html
<input id="id_nome" name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase" value="teste" autofocus required>
```

Comment: funcionou blz, porém preciso capturar o valor em mais um momento quando estou pegando os dados de um post do formulário: `jQuery(this).serializeArray()` ele ainda traz minusculo, seria o caso de abrir outra pergunta?

Comment: @InteliderSistemas Editei o post, quando for capturar o valor atribua primeiro em uma variável convertendo o mesmo para maiúsculo. Acredito que assim funcione e armazene como maiúsculo.