# Capturar dados do form e transformar para UPPERCASE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o input:

```
 <input id="id_nome" name="nome" type="text" class="form-control input-style" style="text-transform: uppercase" autofocus required>
```

Tenho a seguinte função em Jquery:

```
$(function () {
        $('.form').submit(function () {
            //serializando os campos do formulário
            var dados = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
            var obj = dados;
            alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Apesar dos dados estarem em maiúsculo no input, no JSON que é exibido no alert ele fica em minusculo. Como faço para convertê-lo em maiúsculo?

Comment: Só você aplicar upperCase nas propriedades que quer, igual [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220140/uppercase-input-n%c3%a3o-funciona-em-document-getelementbyid). Algo como: `obj.campo = obj.campo.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Qual é a diferença desta pra sua pergunta anterior? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220140/uppercase-input-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-document-getelementbyid

Comment: @bfavaretto o problema é que ele converte todos os campos do json para maiusculo: `{"NAME":"ID","VALUE":""},{"NAME":"NOME","VALUE":"ASDASDA"}`, sendo que no Rest o nome dos campos é minusculo, então ele não aceita. Teria que ficar assim: `[{"name":"id","value":""},{"name":"nome","value":"ASDASDA"}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```js
jQuery(':input').keyup(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
$('.form').submit(function () {
    //serializando os campos do formulário
    var dados = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
    var obj = dados;
    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">

<input id="id_nome" name="nome" type="text" class="form-control input-style" autofocus required>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Em resumo: retirei o `css` que mandava exibir tudo em maiúsculo e adicionei um script que converterá para maiúsculo automaticamente cada caractere inserido pelo usuário em qualquer `input` do formulário. Assim todos os dados inseridos em qualquer `input` serão salvos em maiúsculo quando você mandar serializar.

Caso não seja a intenção aplicar o efeito de `UpperCase` automático em todos os campos, você pode aplicar a apenas um campo ou conjunto de campos, utilizando o `id` do campo desejado ou aplicando uma `class` para os campos em que deseja aplicar o efeito.

```
jQuery('#idCampo').keyup(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

ou

```
jQuery('.class').keyup(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: funcionou blz. obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, editei o post acrescentando como você colocaria o script caso desejasse aplicar somente a um campo específico ou a um conjunto de campos do formulário.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode converter o valor para `uppercase` e reatribuir ao input o valor em uppercase em algum evento do input.

Veja o exemplo abaixo onde eu altero o valor no evento `blur` (quando perde o foco), assim quando você for acessar o valor do input ele já estará como você espera.

```js
document.getElementById('meuInput').addEventListener('blur', function() {
  this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
});

document.getElementById('verValor').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var valorMeuInput = document.getElementById('meuInput').value;
  console.log(valorMeuInput);
});
```

```css
.meuInput {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="meuInput" />
<button type="button" id="verValor">Ver valor</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso de uma única vez no envio do form, assim não sobrecarrega o js com eventos desnecessários.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
    var data = {};
    jQuery(this).find('input[type!=submit], select').each(function(){
        // JOGA OS VALORES EM UPPER CASE PARA O OBJETO DATA QUE VAI SER ENVIADO
        data[this.getAttribute('name')] = this.value.toUpperCase();
    }).serialize();
    console.log(data);
});
```

```css
input{
    text-transform: uppercase; /* ENGANA O USUARIO MOSTRANDO QUE ESTA TUDO EM MAIÚSCULO*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input name="nome" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: só depois que marquei a resposta do Leandro é que vi a sua. A dele funcionou, porém, como estou usando CORDOVA para funcionar tanto em paginas webs quanto em IOS, ANDROID, WINDOWS PHONE a sua opção foi a melhor. A dele fica dando erro nos aplicativos para celular. Ela funciona bem apenas em paginas WEB. Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 0):

O que você está procurando é a função `toUpperCase`

```
JSON.stringify(obj).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: o problema é que ele converte todos os campos do json para maiusculo: `{"NAME":"ID","VALUE":""},{"NAME":"NOME","VALUE":"ASDASDA"}`, sendo que no Rest o nome dos campos é minusculo, então ele não aceita. Teria que ficar assim: `[{"name":"id","value":""},{"name":"nome","value":"ASDASDA"}]`